# mongodb - How to carry over indexes while doing file backup

Tags: mongodb, indexing, backup

We have a cluster of mongo servers. We stop one of the mongo servers and copy all the data files except admin and journal and tar into one file.

We untar the file in our test environments. Though we get all the data carried over properly, we don't get the indexes carried over.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The indexes are stored with the data files. How are you checking if the indexes exist after restoring the backup? What version(s) of MongoDB are you backing up from and restoring to? To ensure backup integrity, I would also recommend copying over all the files rather than excluding journal & admin directories.

Comment: That is especially true for the journal files...

Comment: I am doing the db.collection.getIndexes() on the DB to list the indexes in the  restored environment. I am backing up from 2.6.0 and restoring in 2.6.7. Thanks for the suggestions on the Journals and admins, It makes sense. I will be adding them to the backup.

Comment: I finally found out that it is not carrying the indexes because the instance from where I'm copying the data files doesn't have the index. Looks like the indexes I created in the Primary is not replicated automatically to the secondaries. Trying to find if there is a way to do that.